# Not getting any response from json

Tags: javascript, html, json, treeview

Hi in the below am not getting any response json using java script.I want to display json data as a treeview.

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSON VIEW</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsonview.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/jsonview.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="root"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    fetch('example.json')
    .then((res)=> {
      return res.text();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      jsonView.format(data, '.root');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your developper tool from google Chrome by pressing F12, then look in network XHR what's happening :)

Comment: index.html:14 Fetch API cannot load file:///D:/json-view-master/src/example.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Comment: Ok, so you try to call json by path. You should use a real link like http://...
or ::localhost/...

Comment: i had tried like this "http://localhost:8080/example.json" still it is not working

Comment: Because you have to run a sever like wamp if you are on windows.
If you use Windows, install wamp then put your files in www folder